# how can I count the number of keypress and change of input regarding this?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that change between input text, automatically depending on the number of characters entered, I have tried different approaches and have read many threads in Stackoverflow, but even though some of the solutions worked, I honestly did not understand the code as I am pretty new to coding, so I tried to implement mine, this is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>


</head>
<body>  
    <input type=text id="inp1" placeholder="Nombre" onkeydown=cambiarInput() />
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp2" placeholder="Apellidos" onkeydown=cambiarInput2()/>
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp3" placeholder="Dni"/>
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp4" placeholder="Direccion"/>
    <br/>   
    <input type=button value="Enviar" />
</body>
</html>


function cambiarInput(){
    let input1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
    let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
    if(input1.value.length == 2){   
        input2.focus();
    }
}

function cambiarInput2(){
    let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
    let input3 = document.getElementById('inp3');
    if(input2.value.length == 2){
        input2.blur();
        input3.focus();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeypress' of null at data.js:11`

What am I doing wrong???? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = () => {
document.getElementById('inp1').onkeypress = function(){
     let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
     if(textLength(this.value)){
        input2.setActive();
    }
   }
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('inp1').onkeypress = function(){
     let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
     if(textLength(this.value)){
        input2.setActive();
    }
  }
}
```

This is because you are calling the code before the page is loaded and that element is undefined.

For the second part of the question you could try using `.focus()` to select the second input.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('inp1').onkeypress = function(){
     let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
     if(textLength(this.value)){
        input2.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

For getting the textValue you should be doing this

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('inp1').onkeypress = function(){
     let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
     if(textLength(document.getElementById('inp1').value)){
        input2.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

or you need to bind the function to the object.

```
window.onload = function() {
let input1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
input1.onkeypress = function(){
     let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
     if(textLength(this.value)){
        input2.focus();
    }
  }.bind(input1)
}
```

Edit: Code call should be in quotations

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>


</head>
<body>  
    <input type=text id="inp1" placeholder="Nombre" onkeydown="cambiarInput()" />
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp2" placeholder="Apellidos" onkeydown="cambiarInput2()"/>
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp3" placeholder="Dni"/>
    <br/>
    <input type=text id="inp4" placeholder="Direccion"/>
    <br/>   
    <input type=button value="Enviar" />
</body>
</html>


function cambiarInput(){
    let input1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
    let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
    if(input1.value.length == 2){   
        input2.focus();
    }
}

function cambiarInput2(){
    let input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
    let input3 = document.getElementById('inp3');
    if(input2.value.length == 2){
        input2.blur();
        input3.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I see what you mean, but yet is not working I do not get it to switch to next input when the inp1 has 10 characters, I have tried with inp.value.length and with the keypress count, I do not know what I am missing....

Comment: Where does this.value come from and have you tried using .focus instead of .SetActive

Comment: Ok, I changed a bit the code so it works in the first input, it changes from input1 to input2, but it does not change from input2 to input3... any thoughts???

Comment: Add quotations around your function calls in onkeydown as shown in the edit